# mongodb aggregate with $group and $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to perform a "group by" on a table and "join" it with another table.
Corresponding SQL statement would be:

```
SELECT T1.total, T1.email, T1.type, table_2.name FROM
(SELECT SUM(amount) AS total, email, type 
FROM table_1
GROUP BY email, type) T1
INNER JOIN table_2
on T1.email = table_2.email
```

But since mongodb still doesn't have inner join feature, I tried to use "$lookup" and do the task. here's my code:

```
db.table_1.aggregate([
{$group : {_id : {email: "$email", type:"$type"},total: { $sum: "$amount" }}},
{$lookup: {from: "table_2", localField: "email", foreignField: "email", as: "details"}} ]);
```

But in the results I'm getting, details returns and empty object:

```
{ "_id" : { "user" : "b@b.com", "type" : "Car" }, "total" : 2, "details" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : { "user" : "a@a.com", "type" : "Bike" }, "total" : 3, "details" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : { "user" : "a@a.com", "type" : "Car" }, "total" : 1, "details" : [ ] }
```

But if I run the query without using $group, it works fine. So I'm wondering whether the $group and $lookup functions cannot be used together. If so is there a work-around or what would be the optimal way to get the query done?

[mongo db version I'm using: > db.version() 3.2.7]

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I found the answer to the problem. The reason why I got empty array was the way I've used the localField inside the $lookup.

Since I'm trying to join the table_2 with the $group result of the table_1, the local field should be "_id.email".

So the working query would be:

```
db.table_1.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : {email: "$email", type:"$type"},total: { $sum: "$amount" }}},
    {$lookup: {from: "table_2", localField: "_id.email", foreignField: "email", as: "details"}},
    {$match: {details: {$ne: []}}}
]);
```

Thanks @Wake and @Clement for help

Comment: Makes sense.  I didn't realize you were getting the empty array for email address that should have been a match.

Comment: why order of $match stage is last in sequence of aggregate?

Answer (score 7):

If you want your **$lookup** to work like an **INNER JOIN**, that is, you don't want results unless there is at least one matching document in the lookup table, you can add a **$match** at the end comparing your lookup table results to an empty array **[ ]**:

```
db.table_1.aggregate([
    {$group : {_id : {email: "$email", type:"$type"},total: { $sum: "$amount" }}},
    {$lookup: {from: "table_2", localField: "email", foreignField: "email", as: "details"}},
    {$match: {details: {$ne: []}}}
]);
```

Comment: This made me realize I had confused foreign with local fields in my dataset.

Answer (score 1):

From Mongo version 3.2 onwards $lookup is used to support left-outer join.

> I'm wondering whether the $group and $lookup functions cannot be used
>   together.

$group and $lookup can be used together.

> How to Use it for INNER JOIN

You have add one more condition to filter the results. Use $match. 
You can also try with $in.

References

https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

http://www.clusterdb.com/mongodb/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-in-mongodb-3-2

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/